# Convert Mode DataFrame R

Tags: r, dataframe

Enough question have been asked on how to convert all the values of a data.frame from one mode to another. This raises the following question: how to convert specific columns of a data.frame in R? I have the following:

```
# @param dataFrame the data.frame to be transformed
# @param start the column which first needs to be rewritten to numeric data
# @param end the column which needs to be rewritten to numeric data as last
# @param exlude the columns that need to be excluded from rewriting to numeric data


asNumericData <- function (dataFrame,start,end,exclude) {

   i <- start
   asNumericMatrix <- matrix(nrow = length(dataFrame), ncol = ncol(dataFrame))

   while (i <= end) {
       if (!(i %in% exclude)) {
          asNumericMatrix <- as.numeric(as.character(dataFrame[,i]))
       }
       i <- i + 1
   }

   return (asNumericMatrix)

}
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Error in asNumericMatrix[, i] <- as.numeric(as.character(dataFrame[, i])) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What am I doing wrong? Any other suggestions on how to convert specific columns (or rather exclude columns) from a certain mode to another are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've done it in the past. Given a vector of columns, iterate over them (via lapply), and do your as.character, as.numeric, as.factor, etc...

```
df <- data.frame(v=c("B","C","A"), w=c(12,14,17), h=c(1,2,3))
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ v: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 2 3 1
 $ w: num  12 14 17
 $ h: num  1 2 3
cols <- c("w", "h")
df[,cols] <- lapply(df[,cols], as.character)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ v: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 2 3 1
 $ w: chr  "12" "14" "17"
 $ h: chr  "1" "2" "3"
```